# Get same /etc in different Operation Systems

Tags: debian, systemd, embedded

I have an embedded system with 3 operating systems (self-created Debian 9.4 with 4.14.40-rt Kernel). Each operating system is on a different partition. A bootchooser sets up the system so that when one operating system does not start, the next one is started. Furthermore, this Bootchooser can also provide these 3 partitions with an update. The Debian systems uses `systemd` for initialization.

This works so well. However, I now have the problem that the 3 operating systems contain a different `/etc` directory. However, these should be synchronized and not overwritten when updating the system.

How do you do that right?

My idea was to copy the data from `/etc` to another partition and linking to it does not work properly. Because `/etc/fstab` only lazily reads the additional partition.

Comment: Why then not have the /etc content in its own partition, mounted by all 3 systems? You may however get into problems, for example if you upgrade one system, the other ones will get confused.

Comment: This was my first attempt, but Systemd needs some files before, before /etc and the other partitions are mounted. e.g. /etc/hostname, services, ifup, and ifdown scripts for the Network

after switching with the mounts, a lot of the software will not start anymore

Comment: That's right, I just need to mount `/etc`. However, how can I do this, that the partition is mounted before systemd starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Unix & Linux StackExchange.

[systemd does not support /etc/ on a separate partition](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1075).

Your next best option would to be sync key files between the 3 operating systems.

You might follow the pattern of [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/) and have a central repo that all 3 OSes sync from. You'll have some bootstrapping problems to deal with, for example setting up the networking connection to connect to a site to pull down details of how to setup the network connection...

Your time may be better spent working on updating your design so you only need one embedded operating system on the device.

Comment: You may also run into configuration file problems if a specific configuration file has a directive that a version of the software in another OS can't handle because of mismatch across the various versions of software in the OS.  That would be a problem that wouldn't be able to be solved by this answer.  (Still a good answer though)

Comment: Then I'll sync another way about the settings (maybe just a small part of the settings). The requirements for the 3 operating systems are prescribed by the customer. Should the fail-safety be confirmed in case of a faulty patch. I will also look at the software etcd, but will not be possible in this case. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.